# Gulp inplace replacement of the version-ed CSS and JS files in the source HTML file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using gulp to do a revision of my js and css as part of my build process. Here is how I am doing it atm.

```
gulp.task("revision", function(){
  return gulp.src(["assets/**/*.css", "assets/**/*.js"])

    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

What the above code does is to create a new folder called dist\assets and keep the version(ified) files there

[image]

I am then trying to use the generated app*.js and the app*.css (in the dist/assets folder) in my "existing" index.html file. I am using gulp-rev-replace plugin for that.

```
gulp.task("revreplace", ["revision"], function(){
  var manifest = gulp.src("./" + 'dist' + "/rev-manifest.json");

  return gulp.src('.' + "/index.html")
    .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

But the above code is creating a new file (index.html) in the dist folder. Though this works - but I will be more than happy if it was using the original HTML file. Is there a way I can accomplish that.

A sample code would suit me very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer though, I came across exact same need and just figured it out.

in the function `replaceContents()`, the source code use

```
contents = contents.split(unreved).join(reved)
```

to replace original file name with versioined file name.
We can obviously use a regular expression to replace any filename with fingerprint.

and the line

```
var unreved = options.modifyUnreved ? options.modifyUnreved(rename.unreved) : rename.unreved;
```

reveals we can use `option.modifyUnreved` to change `unreved` to our `regRule`

so in the gulpfile.js

```
revplace({
    manifest: manifest,
    modifyUnreved: function(filename){
        var tmp = filename.split(".");
        tmp[0] = tmp[0] + "(?:-[a-z0-9]{10})?";
        return new RegExp(tmp.join('.'), 'ig');
    }
})
```

and it can replace static filenames in place